# Realtek HD audio drivers can't be installed

Tags: sound, realtek

I am receiving the following error on `make install` as suggested in the Realtek Audio driver package.
I installed the driver from [this](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) website.

The error I am getting is:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
if [ -L /usr/include/sound ]; then \
  rm -f /usr/include/sound; \
 ln -sf /home/sachin/Downloads/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18 (2)/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa/include/sound /usr/include/sound; \   
 else \
rm -rf /usr/include/sound; \
install -d -m 755 -g root -o root /usr/include/sound; \
for f in include/sound/*.h; do \
    install -m 644 -g root -o root $f /usr/include/sound; \
done \
fi
/bin/sh: 3: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
Makefile:188: recipe for target 'install-headers' failed
make: *** [install-headers] Error 2
```

Please help me resolve it.
Thank you.

Comment: What is your OS? Why are you trying to install these drivers?

Comment: Because the music player is prouducing distorted sound... Version ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Have you tried Pulse Audio Equalizer? I have found the sound quality is as good as that produced by Realtek, and no distortion. Realtek and Linux don't work together too easily.

Comment: @PaulBenson would give IT a try. Thank you. And any suggestions on how to resolve this error?

Comment: You have to get used to the idea that Linux is different to Windows, and that big manufacturers like Realtek are more interested in supplying out-of-the-box drivers for Microsoft than for Linux, where open-source software is used instead. I listen to HD audio on CDs, music downloads, watching movies, etc,  through decent headphones using VLC player with PAE. I'm very satisfied with what I'm hearing. I'd say forget Realtek.

Comment: Use `pavucontrol` and `alsmixer` to set levels in both ALSA and Pulseaudio. Pulseaudio level can be set above 100% and can sound distorted, but if level in ALSA can be increased Pulseaudio level can be lowered

Answer (score -2):

You must put `sudo` before the command you typed as an example
`sudo ./configure`